# Can't get value using id

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I can't get the value using id. In my code I put like this

**view**

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $add->class;?>" name="cls_<?php echo $add->id;?>" id="cls_<?php echo $add->id;?>"/>
```

Here I got A

But I can't get the value using this

**script**

```
function Add(id){ 
  var cls = document.getElementById('cls_'+id).value;
  alert(cls);
}
```

Comment: First alrert the id which you are passing to function and if it returns proper than check that input have valid id by inspecting with firebug.

Comment: i got the id bt not value

Comment: Are you sure `$add->id` and `$add->class` have the proper values? The javascript in itself works just fine with static values, as can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/2nz272sk/

Comment: What's the HTML code generated by that PHP?

Comment: Rose use proper debug tools (eg. firebug, CTRL+SHIFT+I in other browsers) and check what the input values is. Use `console.log` to log both `id`, the element you get and the value.

Comment: i do the same u mentioned

Comment: Try adding a `<?php var_dump($add); ?>` in your view above the input and put the output in your question, so we can see what the `$add` object looks like.

Comment: alert shows undefined

Comment: @Rose what did `<?php var_dump($add); ?>` gave?? can you add in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First step you must making sure for this variable `$add->id;`, you can check it in inspect element of your browser. Then as I know the value function of jQuery is `.val()`. so try this `document.getElementById('cls_'+id).val();`. Hope it helps you :)

Comment: dont mix javascript and jquery.

Comment: oh yeah, thanks for this. I think thats can be better user jQuery. So like this ('#cls_'+id).val();

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below, if even then not working then please check - $add varaible data using var_dump($add) or print_r($add).

Please check fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sashant9/tm7ukbqe/

php -->

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $add->class;?>" name="<?php echo "cls_".$add->id;?>" id="<?php echo "cls_".$add->id;?>"/>
```

jquery -->

```
function Add(id){ 
  var cls = document.getElementById('cls_'+id).value;
  alert(cls);
}
```